# Does RAM have any kind of controller in it?

Tags: memory, cpu

I have a problem understanding it (maybe it's a language barrier and/or lack of good articles in my native language).

Let's consider a casual consumer PC.

So there is a CPU. Nowadays the CPU has a MMU (Memory management unit) that takes care of writing and reading from/to RAM.

How does it work?

Does it read straight from the RAM or is it more like a middleware between CPU and the memory?

e.g.

CPU ("Hey I have this virtual address - give me data stored there") ->
MMU ("OK, this virtual adress looks like that as physical address") ->
RAM ("???");

Does RAM say "I'll handle it - here's your data" (have some kind of a controller in it) or MMU is doing it (reading straight from RAM)?

Comment: By *"RAM"* presumably you are referring to the main memory of the computer.    You're conflating the MMU with the memory controller.  Prior to the Intel 386, PCs did not have a MMU, but all computers/PCs have a memory controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either way and would depend on the modules implementation.

[Wikipedia on Memory Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller), emphasis added.

> Reading and writing to DRAM is performed by selecting the row and column data addresses of the DRAM as the inputs to the multiplexer circuit, where the **demultiplexer on the DRAM** uses the converted inputs to select the correct memory location and return the data, which is then passed back through a multiplexer to consolidate the data in order to reduce the required bus width for the operation.

How that multiplexer is implemented would depend on the chip.